# Бот не отправляет сообщения

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вот я сделал код, для просмотра своего либо кого-то баланса:

```py
#Просмотр баланса пользователя
@bot.command()
async def balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Баланс',color = 0x4788C9,
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cach FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
            )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        emb = discord.Embed(title='Баланс',color = 0x4788C9,
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{member}** составляет **{cursor.execute("SELECT cach FROM users WHERE id = {}".format(member.id)).fetchone()[0]}**"""
            )
        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Но почему-то когда я прописываю команду (>balance) ничего не происходит, а в консоле ничего не пишет, помогите исправить пожалуйста!

Comment: У вас стоит ивент `on_command_error`?

Comment: Именно для этой команды, нет

Comment: Если у вас стоит `on_command_error` без вывода в консоль, то логично, что он не будет  выводить ошибку

Comment: У меня нету `on_command_error`, понимаете? Ошибки в консоле тоже нету, просто бот не выводит сообщения в чат, возможно ембед не правильно прописан, посмотрите пожалуйста повнимательнее